# Low-speed USB Device Reset Using xhci_hcd

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, drivers

How to fix this reset?

This is a Debian server. There is a constant and repeating message on the console/syslog:

```
kernel: usb 1-7.4: reset low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```

I know that this device is the IPMI's virtual keyboard and mouse. After resetting the IPMI, the following log entries occur, but after a while, the problem starts up again.

```
kernel: usb 1-7.3: USB disconnect, device number 3
kernel: cdc_ether 1-7.3:2.0 enXXXXX: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-0000:02:00.0-7.3, CDC Ethernet Device
kernel: usb 1-7.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
kernel: usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 2
kernel: usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=046b, idProduct=ff01, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 1-7: Product: Virtual Hub
kernel: usb 1-7: Manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc.
kernel: usb 1-7: SerialNumber: serial
kernel: hub 1-7:1.0: USB hub found
kernel: hub 1-7:1.0: 5 ports detected
kernel: usb 1-7.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-7.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046b, idProduct=ffb0, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 1-7.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: usb 1-7.3: Product: Virtual Ethernet
kernel: usb 1-7.3: Manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc.
kernel: usb 1-7.3: SerialNumber: 1234567890
kernel: cdc_ether 1-7.3:2.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:02:00.0-7.3, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:00:00:00:00:00
systemd-udevd: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
systemd-udevd: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
kernel: cdc_ether 1-7.3:2.0 enXXXXX: renamed from usb0
systemd-udevd: Using default interface naming scheme 'v247'.
systemd-udevd: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
kernel: usb 1-7.4: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
kernel: usb 1-7.4: New USB device found, idVendor=046b, idProduct=ff10, bcdDevice= 1.00
kernel: usb 1-7.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: usb 1-7.4: Product: Virtual Keyboard and Mouse
kernel: usb 1-7.4: Manufacturer: American Megatrends Inc.
kernel: input: American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.4/1-7.4:1.0/0003:046B:FF10.0003/input/input5
kernel: hid-generic 0003:046B:FF10.0003: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse] on usb-0000:02:00.0-7.4/input0
kernel: input: American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.4/1-7.4:1.1/0003:046B:FF10.0004/input/input6
kernel: hid-generic 0003:046B:FF10.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse] on usb-0000:02:00.0-7.4/input1
systemd-logind: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (American Megatrends Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse)
```

Here is the reset again, but reflecting the new device number assigned after the IPMI has been reset.

```
kernel: usb 1-7.4: reset low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
```

This is the output from `lsusb`. The IPMI components are the only USB devices.

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046b:ff10 American Megatrends, Inc. Virtual Keyboard and Mouse
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046b:ffb0 American Megatrends, Inc. Virtual Ethernet
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046b:ff01 American Megatrends, Inc. Virtual Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: and what is the business related question or issue in here?

Comment: The message is filling up the logs. Is there a way to a) make a change to the system software to correct for what is happening? or b) suppress the log message?

Comment: I am afraid this is hardware issue (it's buggy or broken). What's the hardware (the server model, the motherboard model, the IPMI BMC model)? Did you try to update IPMI BMC firmware?

Comment: The issue appears to have gone away after flashing the IPMI firmware.